# CSS not being applied to element

Tags: css, html

I have looked at other questions and nothing seems to be working. I have a DIV that is to create a popup box and another one that make the background grey. I have used the same approach on another page and it works fine however on this current page the CSS is not being applied to either of the DIV tags. Here is the HTML

```
<section id="goals" class="goals">
    <button id="addgoal" onclick="popupadd(); return false;">Add Goal</button>

    <div id="darkLayer" class="darkl" style="display:none"></div>       
    <div id="addgoalpop" class="agpop" style="display:none">

        <p><span class="">LogIn</span></p>
        <P><span class="title">Email</span> <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="emailbox"></asp:TextBox></P>
        <P><span class="title">Password</span> <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="passbox" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></P>
        <p><Label id="errormsg"></Label></p>           

    </div>   
</section>
```

Here is the CSS that should be applied to both of the DIV tags

```
.agpop {
    padding:10px 10px 35px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;

    border:solid 1px black;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:100;

    height:150px;
    margin-top:-200px;

    width:200px;
    margin-left:-100px;
}

.darkl {
    background-color: white;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.50; /* FireFox */
    z-index: 20;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

The JavaScript I am Using

```
   function popupadd()
   {
      document.getElementById("addgoalpop").style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display = "";
   }
```

Can anyone understand why this is?

Comment: You have `display: none` set in the HTML for those divs... why? That is hiding them. Alternatively, you can add `!important` to every property in your CSS file, but this is awful and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I think he is trying to make a popup. So it should be hidden before his event is fired. What happens - the popup wont show up or there is no styling at all?

Comment: @TylerH `Alternatively, you can add !important to every property in your CSS file`. No... Just no.

Comment: @d-bro82 the problem is that this is not a good way to do it; by default, in-line styles override CSS styles. So he should move the hidden code to CSS as a `:before` pseudo-selector class or something

Comment: @Ruddy Sorry, I wasn't seriously suggesting it, only mentioning it as a possibility. I've edited my suggestion to be more clear :-) I figured it was obvious with "every property in your CSS file" that I wasn't serious

Comment: yes they are hidden then on the button click the display gets changed in order to show the popup

Comment: So whats the problem? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2X2W6/1)

Comment: @Ruddy probably that he doesn't have the JS that you created :-P

Comment: @TylerH Well they didn't give it to us so I had to make my own to test it. OP you should give us your Javascript, because as you can see by my demo it works fine.

Comment: tried my it all in JSFiddle with my JS and it all works fine I am just at a loss as to why it wont work within the page I am working on. As I said I used the same approach on another page and it worked fine

Comment: @ProgrammingRookie So you knew it worked in a JSFiddle but still came here with the same code excepting us to know what code is on your real page? That makes no sense, we cannot solve this problem without ALL relevant code. So create a JSFiddle of that or you may as well delete this question.

Comment: @ProgrammingRookie Are you using jQuery and including the files you need to run it?

Comment: not using jQuery simply just setting the display via JavScript on a button press

Comment: It shows and hides the "addgoalpop" div it just doesn't seem to be applying the CSS to the div

Comment: @ProgrammingRookie As I said then you need to include all your code if you think something is affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `style="display:none"` is causing the problem. Try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your divs

```
<div id="darkLayer" class="darkl" style="display:none"></div>       
 <div id="addgoalpop" class="agpop" style="display:none">
```

To this

```
<div id="darkLayer" class="darkl"></div>       
 <div id="addgoalpop" class="agpop">
```

Or else they won't show up, if you want to make them hidden, and popup later, you can do something that triggers an event and changes the style display on those divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your darkLayer has nothing inside of it.. It looks like you may have ment to use it as a container for the content of addgoalpop.

If that is your intent, move the closing div tag below all of the addgoalpop content

Comment: That `div` is a cover, it acts as the pop-ups background. This is intended. That also means this is incorrect, this is more of a comment anyways.

Comment: I understand that it is supposed to be the background of the pop up. If the darkLayer was used though as also a container, the code would be cleaned up a bit by only needing to show/hide one div instead of two. This may have uncovered an issue for OP which may have been giving them an issue in displaying their popup.